# How can I animate multiple buttons simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, translate-animation

I am trying to do a Translate Animation on multiple ImageViews(Buttons) simultaneously. The TranslateAnimations however, vary for each ImageView, so I am putting them in an AnimationSet. The problem is, that somehow the animation is never even run... I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<TranslateAnimation> animlist = new ArrayList<TranslateAnimation>();
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

//The following for-loop is actually running inside two other for loops... I'm        skimming it down a little for you guys
for(int i = ROWS-1; i > row;i--){
    if(!usedFields[column][i]){
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)GameLayout.findViewWithTag(""+row+","+column);
        TranslateAnimation transanim = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,-(i-row)*letterHeight,0);
        transanim.setDuration(1000);
        iv.setAnimation(transanim);
        animlist.add(transanim);
        break;
    }
}

for (TranslateAnimation anim : animlist){
    set.addAnimation(anim);         
}

set.startNow();
```

Thank you, I appreciate it!